# Работа с ООП и MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ооп, mysqli

Добрый день. Есть объект для работы с MySQL (например SafeMySQL), как с ним лучше работать в других объектах? Каждый раз при создание объекта добавлять в него ссылка на объект с MySQL?

Comment: `class SafeMySQL extends mysqli`? Чем не ООП?

Answer (score 2):

На сколько я понимаю в SafeMySQL реализованно создание подключений к БД и хранение созданных подключений(стек подключений). Лучше всего сделать так: когда необходимо сделать обращение к БД забирать из стека подключение, работать с ним и возвращать по завершению работы обратно в стек.

Для тесной интеграции БД с ООП языком существует технология [ORM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM). Уже написанно множество [ORM библиотек](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_ORM-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA#PHP). ORM скрывает почти всю работу с БД и с точки зрения программиста выглядит как хранилище объектов.

Обратной стороной ORM является не самое оптимальное использование БД и чаще всего запросы написанные «вручную» работают более эффективно.